# AngularJS databinding through responsemessage not working as expected

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, websocket

Code is as follows

```
var myApp = angular.module("gameModule", []);

myApp.controller("gamecontroller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "test";

    // websocket connection.
    var gameHub = $.connection.socketHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        var clientid = $.connection.hub.id;

        $(function () {
            var user = { signalrsessionid: clientid };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                url: "http://localhost:53629/api/game/signalr",
                contentType: "application/json"

            }).done(function (response) {
                alert(response);
               $scope.responsemessage = response;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and front end code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gameModule">
<head>
<title>game registration</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<!--Automatisch gegenereerde signalR hub script -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

<script src="Scripts/rouletteAngular.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="gamecontroller">
    {{ message }}
    {{ responsemessage }}
</div>
```

So the 'message' is being displayed, the alert box with the response is showing the correct response, but the responsemessage doesnt show any value.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you getting a response message in alert or the object? The response message is probably in response.data

Comment: $scope.responsemessage = response.data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must call $scope.$apply(); or $scope.$digest(); after setting $scope.responsemessage = response; because you are using jQuery ajax call, which is outside Angulars context.

**EDIT:**

here you have nice way to use SignalR in AngularJS:
http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html